# How to generate ELF file format for JIT code for GDB?

Tags: compilation, gdb, elf, jit, dwarf

**Background:**

I am generating a JIT code (which generates x86-64 code). After the end of JIT process, I have a .text section, a .data section and a .eh_frame section generated (.eh_frame is used for stack unwinding). I am able to execute this JIT code successfully. But the issue is GDB. I want to be able to debug this JIT code using GDB (specifically the 'backtrace' command of GDB should work).

**Problem:**

I need to tell GDB about this loaded JIT code (in particular I need to tell GDB about .eh_frame so it can use that frame for stack-unwinding). I see that GDB has a JIT interface: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/JIT-Interface.html

**Possible Solutions:**

There are two options here:

1. Hand over a ELF file to GDB
2. Write a Customer Jit-Reader plugin to handle debugging of custom object file.

Right now I have a custom object file (just bunch of three independent sections loaded into memory). I don't want to write my own Jit Reader plugin.

**Blocking Issue:**

Does anyone knows existing code that will help me package these three independent sections into a simple ELF file (which I can then register with GDB by calling *__jit_debug_register_code*())? I am guessing all I need to do is write some header (conforming to ELF specifications) which have names and pointers to the section. Is there existing open source code for this or if not, can someone point me towards how to do this packaging myself?

I need bare minimum ELF file so that GDB is happy (I don't need to Load the ELF file as .text and .data section are already loaded)

Answer (score 1):

`libelf` could be of help for constructing an ELF object. There are open-source implementations available at:

- [elftoolchain](https://sourceforge.net/p/elftoolchain/wiki/libelf/) (BSD licensed)
- [elfutils](https://sourceware.org/elfutils/) (GPL).